# Function to centralize any element on screen crashes only in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble with a code that I was caught from the internet to centralize an element on the screen.

Someone has passed from this situation?

The simple code is (in jQuery):

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2) +
        $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
    this.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) +
        $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
    return this;
};
```

Comment: What is problem? It works fine (as it seems)? http://jsfiddle.net/WSNCr/

Comment: Do you mean to keep it centered when the window is resized?

Comment: Really nevermind. I'm confused now. In my real application, I use this code, but, in my real context the firefox doesn't centralize the element. In real, the element is centralized, but only in horizontal. Patrick, I use in resize funcion, is really an especific problem, =[.

Comment: show your html, without seeing the context within you are using this i can only assume that the parent element that contains the element you are trying to center also has a `position` style set, which would make  the element you are trying to center to be positioned based off of it, instead of the body.

Comment: Patrick, the parent element is the body. And it doesn't has any position style. =[